# Loop the select statement in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a store procedure shown below

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rptlabelPrint] --'HKOHBLAE11/0007'  ,'','HKO'  
    (                                                          
    @Code varchar(25),
    @Format int=0  ,
    @Branch varchar(25)=''
    )                                                          
    AS                                                        

    SELECT 

       HB.HB_cCode as HBCode,
       HB.MB_cCode as MBCode,
       PO.PO_cShortName as Dest,
       PS.PO_cShortName as Source
    FROM 
    SHI_HOUSEBLHDR HB
    left join SHI_PORTS PO on HB.PO_cDischargePortCode = PO.PO_cCode 
    left join SHI_PORTS PS on HB.PO_cLoadPortCode = PS.PO_cCode 

   where   HB.HB_cCode=@Code and HB.br_ccode=@Branch
```

Here it reurns a single row. 
But i need to pass a integer value to parameter `@Format` and if it set to `2` the select statement must execute 2 times and returns the two rows. If its set 4 it returns 4 times of the same row. is it possible to loop the select statement and return the rows

Comment: the fact you want to 'loop' a select suggests you are doing it incorrectly...

Comment: @MitchWheat has a point but there might be good reasons why you need this that we cannot imagine. You need to clarify if you want 1 execution of your SELECT that will return @Format times the same row (you need an  auxilliary or number tables) or actually multiple executions of the SELECT statement (multiple result sets, each with a single row - a `while` loop will do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temp table to store and return the result

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rptlabelPrint] 
(                                                          
@Code varchar(25),
@Format int=0  ,
@Branch varchar(25)=''
)                                                          
AS    
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable(HBCode VARCHAR(25),MBCode VARCHAR(25),Dest VARCHAR(25),Source VARCHAR(25))                                                    
WHILE (@Format < 4)
BEGIN

insert  INTO #MyTempTable
SELECT 

   HB.HB_cCode as HBCode,
   HB.MB_cCode as MBCode,
   PO.PO_cShortName as Dest,
   PS.PO_cShortName as Source
FROM 
SHI_HOUSEBLHDR HB
left join SHI_PORTS PO on HB.PO_cDischargePortCode = PO.PO_cCode 
left join SHI_PORTS PS on HB.PO_cLoadPortCode = PS.PO_cCode 

where   HB.HB_cCode=@Code and HB.br_ccode=@Branch


    Set @Format = @Format + 1
END
SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rptlabelPrint] --'HKOHBLAE11/0007'  ,'','HKO'  
    (                                                          
    @Code varchar(25),
    @Format int=0  ,
    @Branch varchar(25)=''
    )                                                          
    AS                                                        

    SELECT 
       HB_cCode as HBCode,
       MB_cCode as MBCode,
       PO_cShortName as Dest,
       PO_cShortName as Source
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
       HB.HB_cCode as HBCode,
       HB.MB_cCode as MBCode,
       PO.PO_cShortName as Dest,
       PS.PO_cShortName as Source
    FROM 
    SHI_HOUSEBLHDR HB
    left join SHI_PORTS PO on HB.PO_cDischargePortCode = PO.PO_cCode 
    left join SHI_PORTS PS on HB.PO_cLoadPortCode = PS.PO_cCode     
    where   HB.HB_cCode=@Code and HB.br_ccode=@Branch
    )T
     Cross JOIN
    (
     SELECT TOP ( @Format ) ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
      CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
     ) AS x(n) ;
```